# An Socket error occurs while using WSAEventSelect in C#

Tags: c#, networking

a problem happened will i was using WSAEventSelect function to handle network event, code as below:

```
AutoResetEvent[] EventArray = new AutoResetEvent[1];

AutoResetEvent clientEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
EventArray[0] = clientEvent; 

if (NetWork.WSAEventSelect(m_clientSocket, EventArray[0], NetWork.FD_READ | NetWork.FD_CLOSE) == -1)
// (m_clientSocket is passed by another function which presents the client socket: m_clientSocket = Socket.EndAccept(ar))
{Console.WriteLine("Get Last Error: {0}",NetWork.WSAGetLastError());}
```

The Definition of WSAEventSelect is:

```
[DllImport("Ws2_32.dll")]
public static extern int WSAEventSelect(Socket s, EventWaitHandle e, int eventType);
```

Also the define of FD_READ and FD_CLOSE are:

```
public const int FD_READ_BIT = 0;
public const int FD_READ = (1 << FD_READ_BIT);
public const int FD_CLOSE_BIT = 5;
public const int FD_CLOSE = (1 << FD_CLOSE_BIT);
```

the return error of the WSAEventSelect function is -1 with last error: 10038 known as: WSAENOTSOCK

Please advice

Thanks

Comment: The error message is pretty clear: you passed an invalid socket handle. How did you initialize `m_clientSocket`? And more importantly, why are you using the native Winsock API, when .NET has very good managed network APIs already?

Comment: This is the first time to use the network API in C#, 1: m_ClientSocket is initialized by another function  "m_ClientSocket = Socket.EndAccept(ar))", and seems like the m_ClientSocket has been initialized, so Im not sure what's wrong here; 2: do you mind light me up about how to use .NET network API to monitor network events? thanks

Comment: MSDN has comprehensive documentation on the proper use of the `Socket` class (which does not include trying to pass a .NET `Socket` instance to an unmanaged function as if it were an unmanaged socket handle), and there are numerous examples on the web, including right here on Stack Overflow. The `Socket` class has two different asynchronous paradigms (`Begin/EndXXX`, and `XXXAsync`), and you can use a `NetworkStream` to use the more modern C# `async`/`await`-based paradigm.